# Can I install Ubuntu on an Acer Swift 1 out of the box

Tags: linux, laptop, bios, bootable-media

I am looking at purchasing an Acer Swift 1 laptop. But I am not interested at using Windows at all.

Do Acer laptops, and more specifically the Acer Swift 1, allow me to access the BIOS on startup, to boot from install media USB?

If so what is the key command?

Comment: Delete or F2 keys should get the bios right after power up.

Answer (score 1):

You can enter BIOS by pressing F2 at boot.
The default boot mode is UEFI.
You can edit boot menu from here...

If it still doesn't work you can disable secure boot and try again

Tip: If you press F12 at boot you can easily access boot menu.
Alt+F10 will take you to the windows recovery menu.

But if your question is simply whether you can install Linux distros on this laptop the answer is yes. 
Good Luck:)